# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Trying to Load UITableView Inside UIView Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, view, controller, tableview

This is starting to drive me insane, as I've followed every instruction I can find online and still can't get this to work- all I'm trying to do is have a view controller with a view that contains a tableview, and have the view controller handle the tableview's operations (i.e. be the delegate and data source for it).

I've set up my view controller and its view, added a tableview to the view in IB, created and connected an IBOutlet from the view controller to the tableview, and set the tableview's data source and delegate to the view controller. I've also made sure the view controller implements the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols in the interface file.

The issue occurs when I then go to add my view controller's view to the window. I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error on the `return UIApplicationMain...` line:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ClareStreamsAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ClareStreamsAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

So basically I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here. As far as I can see I've connected everything in Interface Builder, but is there some other initialization I need to do in the code? And also another interesting point- if I don't connect the data source and delegate outlets from the tableview in IB, the error does not occur and the view loads fine (although obviously I then can't do anything with the tableview).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` indicates that you've over-released some variable. First, look at the log output and check for messages. The most common cause of this is incorrectly managing your ivars. Make sure to always access ivars through your accessors except in `init` and `dealloc`.

The most common way that people mess this up is code like this, where `foo` is an ivar:

```
foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:...]; // Or any method that returns an autorelease
```

The correct code is:

```
self.foo = [NSString stringWithFormat:...];
```

---

**EDIT** I overlooked that you're using ARC. First, make sure you're running the very latest betas, and double-check your logs for the error. Make sure you're always using strong/weak for your properties rather than retain/assign. Read the "Programming with ARC release notes."

Comment: Except I don't think I have any variables like that. In fact in my view controller right now I'm not initializing any variables whatsoever (keeping it bare-bones to fix the problem). So all I have is basically all auto-generated code for the view controller and tableview datasource/delegate. Or is that the issue? Is there some other initialization I have to do for the tableview beyond just adding it and wiring it up in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yep, ARC was the issue. I simply turned it off in the build settings and that fixed the problem. Not ideal, but I don't have time right now to work around Apple's bugs, so I'll wait for the final version to re-implement it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you just turned it off without modifying the code, you'll likely leak all over the place, and you may crash.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what is causing your issues. I had the same problem awhile ago. What was happening was, my UIViews were being deallocated by ARC. For example, try adding this to your UIView's .m file and see if it gets called:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"This bitchass ARC deleted my UIView.");
}
```

The resolution is quite simple. Instead of allocating your UIView as an instance variable, like this...

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchedUpInside
{
    ViewWithTableView *viewWithTableView = [[ViewWithTableView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:viewWithTableView.view];
}
```

...you should allocate your UIView in the parent UIView that loads your UIView:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchedUpInside
{
    self.viewWithTableView = [[ViewWithTableView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:viewWithTableView.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data source for the tableview is being edited without reloading the tableview.

Best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, [NSStringFromClass([ClareStreamsAppDelegate class]) autorelease]);   
}
```

The call to `NSStringFromClass` returns you an autoreleased NSString, but not necessarily in your autorelease pool.  If `NSStringFromClass` sets up its own pool, the string it is returning is getting released, so when the code in your `UIApplicationMain` sends a message to it you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: I tried modifying with that code, but I get an error saying that 'autorelease' is not allowed while 'automatic reference counting' is turned on (I'm targeting iOS 5, latest version of Xcode).